# Can Siphon work to transfer water from lower elevation to higher elevation?

Tags: pressure, water, fluid-statics

I have a tank that is leaking at the bottom and I am trying to transfer water from the bottom by using siphon. I want to transfer the water to another medium in a higher elevation and from there it will be forced into the tank. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If the bottom of the tank into which you wish to transfer the water is higher than the level of water in the existing tank, you cannot use a siphon, you will need a motor-driven pump.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.